# Using java annotations without CDI

Tags: java, annotations, ejb, cdi

I have been searching for a while, but I could not found any usefull informations about my question. is it possible to use Java annotations without initializing annotation implementation with CDI or EJB?

Comment: What kind of annotation ?

Comment: Yes, `@Override` for example.

Comment: Like annotations which would make code simple on desktop java application (Like some special logging - annotating method). Is it possible and how to achieve it? I have had search a lot, but I could not found anything usefull.

Answer (score 3):

You can use annotations as much as you like.

Some annotations are used by the compiler, like @Override, for example. Most annotations are available at runtime also, and are heavily used with reflection.

CDI implementations - for example - use reflection to find injection points and injectable types. If you use the typical CDI annotations, but do not have any CDI implementation in your running program, then it just does nothing. That's it. You could - of course - do the reflective analysis yourself.

One additional note about annotations: If the class file of an annotation is not found in the class patth, the annotation on an element will be silently dropped, so that it is not available anymore for reflective access.

Comment: Nice post! I would be very happy if you could post me some example how to use annotations on desktop java application. I just can't find any example on google :(

Comment: @Dahakka I do not know a special site in the net, so I must refer you to google "java tutorial annotation". There are many articles dealing with annotations. Please take the time for reading them. (I know, it's much.)

Comment: I have read many articles about annotations, but all examples using CDI and I can't use CDI. I need some implementations like @Override annotation, but I can't found any tutorial about it. Thanks!

Comment: Check out some BeanValidation tutorials and examples. Bean validation works without CDI and is really useful whenever you deal user inputs, databases and external services.